# How to make imported target GLOBAL afterwards?

Tags: cmake, dependency-management

From the `FindBoost.cmake` module of CMake 3.8:

```
foreach(COMPONENT ${Boost_FIND_COMPONENTS})
  if(_Boost_IMPORTED_TARGETS AND NOT TARGET Boost::${COMPONENT})
    string(TOUPPER ${COMPONENT} UPPERCOMPONENT)
    if(Boost_${UPPERCOMPONENT}_FOUND)
      if(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS)
        add_library(Boost::${COMPONENT} STATIC IMPORTED)
      else()
        # Even if Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS is OFF, we might have static
        # libraries as a result.
        add_library(Boost::${COMPONENT} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
      endif()
```

and the corresponding comment from the [docu of that module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html):

> It is important to note that the imported targets behave differently than variables created by this module: multiple calls to find_package(Boost) in the same directory or sub-directories with different options (e.g. static or shared) will not override the values of the targets created by the first call.

I see the rational for having the targets not being `GLOBAL`.

However, what is the preferred way of making them global?

I'm used to defining the dependencies of my project in a sub-directory including any `find_package(...)` calls. Consequently, the Boost imported targets are not available in another directory, e.g. `/tests/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
<project_root>
  /3rdparty
    /git-submodule-of-a-small-lib
    /CMakeLists.txt
  /include
    /...
  /tests
    /CMakeLists.txt
  /CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to workaround the problem of having the imported Boost targets not available in the global project scope by including `3rdparty/CMakeLists.txt` not by `add_subdirectory(3rdparty)` but via `include(3rdparty/CMakeLists.txt)` as this evaluates `3rdparty/CMakeLists.txt` in the caller's scope.

Comment: I understand this solves your problem, and this is a good answer, but given Florian's perfect analysis that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

There is a [`IMPORTED_GLOBAL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_GLOBAL.html) target property for this in CMake >= 3.11:

```perl
set_target_properties(Boost::unit_test_framework PROPERTIES IMPORTED_GLOBAL TRUE)
```

For older versions: `find_package()` uses standard `add_library()` calls, so you can always change/extend its functionality to have `IMPORTED` targets always `GLOBAL` with something like:

**3rdparty\CMakeLists.txt**

```perl
function(add_library)
    set(_args ${ARGN})
    if ("${_args}" MATCHES ";IMPORTED")
        list(APPEND _args GLOBAL)
    endif()
    _add_library(${_args})
endfunction()

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
```

**Disclaimer**

As @CraigScott has commented overwriting CMake's build-in functions is dangerous:

- [[CMake] infinite loop when using function overriding](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-March/043320.html)
- [CMake Issue #14357: Defining an override macro/function of add_library more than once causes a segmentation fault](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14357)

**References**

- [CMake Issue #1254: Add new target-property `IMPORTED_GLOBAL`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1254)
- [CMake Issue #1222: [Threads, Boost] Option to create IMPORTED targets with GLOBAL scope](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1222)
- [CMake Issue #17256: Possibility to promote IMPORTED target to IMPORTED GLOBAL](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17256)

Comment: It is not advisable to override functions and then try to call the one being overridden by using the undocumented CMake behavior of calling the same function name but with an underscore prepended. This "call the old implementation" doesn't extend past the first override, meaning if you override it twice, you can never reach the first original function any more. Instead, if the function is overridden in this way twice, you create infinite recursion.

Comment: @CraigScott I see your point and admit that I struggle between the usefulness and maliciousness of overwriting build-in functions. Sometimes it's really required and has saved my day with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818725/cmake-how-to-unit-test-your-own-cmake-script-macros-functions), but yes - since it's not officially supported - it's dangerous to use. I would like to add this officially to CMake with all the proper tests and functionality.